# How to call NtUserSendInput from kernel mode driver?

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver

I have been trying to call `NtUserSendInput` from the win32kfull.sys driver, but I have not gotten far. There are two things that come to my head that I could try, but I figured I asked here to get some advice before I bluescreen again.

1. Scan for the function in memory
2. Bypass the bluescreen and get it from the exported modules

I have tried using offsets, but that doesnt work.
Any help would be apreciated!

Comment: If you are already in the kernel, a keyboard driver lets you bypass the injection flag set on simulated input...

Comment: got any reference to msdn for me?

Comment: Not really. Look at the open source VNC servers, they might use it to send Ctrl+Alt+Del (which SendInput cannot do).